# selecting specific elements from list of lists

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have a list of lists

```
grouplst=[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [9]]
```

I am trying to do an operation like in each iteration this lstoflst are further divided into separate lists.
 eg:

```
for i in range(len(grouplst)):
    for j in range(i+1,len(grouplst)):
        lst1=grouplst[train1]+grouplst[train2]
        lst2=list(set(list(range(1, len(grouplst)))) - set(train_indices))
```

What I am expecting is:

```
In first iteration:
lst1=[0,1,2,3,4,5]
lst2=[6,7,8,9] #all the elements in lstoflst which are not in lst1

In second iteration:
lst1=[3,4,5,6,7,8]
lst2=[0,1,2,9]

 etc.
```

[image]

Also, i created this grouplst by diviving numpy array into different sizes. Is there any other way to do this? I am trying to do Randomsearch CV without Scikitlearn.

Comment: Maybe something like `from itertools import combinations, chain` then `[[list(chain(*x)) for x in combinations(grouplst, i)] for i in range(1, len(grouplst)]` ..?

Comment: @Chris A I had tried but this is not yeilding the correct output.